# I did every thing right with the event handling.However, I am missing something. What is it, please?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

I am trying to write a program that calculates the area and the perimeter of a circle. The program should have two buttons. One for Calculation process. The other is for closing the program. I am missing something with implementing the ActionListener. Would you please help me?

```
import java.awt.* ;
import java.awt.event.* ;
import javax.swing.* ;

public class Circle extends JFrame {

    private JLabel radiusLabel, areaLabel, perimeterLabel ;
    private JTextField radiusText, areaText, perimeterText;
    private JButton calculateButton, exitButton;
    
    private CalculateButtonHandler calculateButtonHandler;
    private ExitButtonHandler exitButtonHandler;
    
    public Circle(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        radiusLabel = new JLabel("radius");
        areaLabel = new JLabel("Area");
        perimeterLabel = new JLabel("Perimeter");
        
        radiusText = new JTextField(10);
        areaText = new JTextField(10);
        perimeterText = new JTextField(10);
        
        calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate") ;
        calculateButtonHandler = new CalculateButtonHandler();
    calculateButtonHandler.addActionListener(calculateButtonHandler);
        exitButton = new JButton("Close") ;
        exitButton.addActionListener(exitButtonHandler);
        
        setTitle("Area and Perimeter of a circle");
        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));
        
        pane.add(radiusLabel);
        pane.add(radiusText);
        pane.add(areaLabel);
        pane.add(areaText);
        pane.add(perimeterLabel);
        pane.add(perimeterText);
        pane.add(calculateButton);
        pane.add(exitButton);
        
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    class CalculateButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

        public CalculateButtonHandler(ActionEvent e) {
            double radius, area, perimeter ;
            
            radius = Double.parseDouble(radiusText.getText());
            area = radius * radius * 3.14 ;
            perimeter = 2 * radius * 3.14 ;
            
            areaText.setText("" + area);
            perimeterText.setText("" + perimeter);
        }
    }
    
        private class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        public ExitButtonHandler() {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Circle c = Circle();
    }
}
```

Comment: The code presented above does not compile. Are you ignoring compilation errors? Fix. Them. First.

Comment: I know that. That's what I've been trying to do for the last two hours before I sent the question.

Comment: *"I did every thing right.."* is not something you write when the **compiler is reporting errors.** What you should have written (or rather copy/pasted) was the first (there are multiple) of the compilation errors!

Comment: if I copy/pasted as you claimed, Then why am I getting **Compilation Errors** ?. I guess I didn't force you to assist me

Comment: *"if I copy/pasted as you claimed, Then why am I getting Compilation Errors ?."* Do you see any connection between.. *"If I ate a banana, then why are my apples falling off the tree?".* No? There is as much logic in that group of words you wrote, so .. I cannot provide an answer to that. *"I guess I didn't force you to assist me"* That's true. It supports the concept that if you guess enough times, you're bound to be right eventually - if only due to random chance. Maybe if you guess another 763 times, you might solve the multiple problems with that very random code above. Good luck with it!

Comment: @JavaBiggener, *I guess I didn't force you to assist me* - so you have time to comment when you are asked to post a better question with more complete information? Yet you have had an answer to fix at least some of the problems over an hour ago and you don't have time to "accept" the answer or even comment whether the suggestion helped? Good luck with future questions.

Answer (score 1):

> I am missing something with implementing the ActionListener.

```
class CalculateButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

    public CalculateButtonHandler(ActionEvent e) {
        double radius, area, perimeter ;
        
        radius = Double.parseDouble(radiusText.getText());
        area = radius * radius * 3.14 ;
        perimeter = 2 * radius * 3.14 ;
        
        areaText.setText("" + area);
        perimeterText.setText("" + perimeter);
    }
}
```

In your code you say you are implementing "ActionListener" but you are not. You did not implement the `actionPerformed(...)` method.

```
public CalculateButtonHandler(ActionEvent e) {
```

should be:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
```